# How to acquire lock on database table?

Tags: oracle

I have to test a scenario in which if data base is down our messages will go into the queue. But i can't do database down.

can anyone tell me how i can lock a table so that above scenario will get tested.

Comment: `select 1 from MyTable for update nowait`?

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko and how it will get released.

Comment: `Commit`; `select ... for update nowait` puts an exclusive lock on (part of) table for performing DML operations (`update`, `delete`); when finished (`commit`/`rollback`) the lock lifted.

Comment: How locking a table would simulate database down scenario?

Comment: @JSapkota: it depends on the extent the routine should be tested. The most accurating approach is *mocking*: we mock driver or whatever to simulate database down behaviour. The simplest scenario (what my routine will do if it can't write down the message for whatever reason) can be simulated with locking

Comment: @DmitryBychenko tried that but record is inserted.

Comment: @jsapkota : on lock also above scenario executes.

Comment: @Arpan Paliwal: be sure that you lock the table in a *different* transaction and you *don't use* autocommit

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: a `select 1 ... for update nowait` will **not** prevent inserts.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I'm very sorry, you're quite right - pessimistic lock allows inserts for sure (it prevents DML `update`\`delete` only). What a blind I've commited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pessimistically lock the whole table, preventing edits (inserts / updates / deletes etc.) using the following :

```
lock table MY_TABLE in exclusive mode nowait;
```

The table lock is removed when the transaction is finished, that is, by issuing a commit or rollback.